# I have a status code checker for urls that gives me a list with the urls+status code - I want to get a message when status 200 is recieved

Tags: python, url, web-crawler, alert, status

I use this status checker since some months. Works flawlessly, although I would love to get a message when a status 200 is found and if not it loops itself and start from the beginning (thinking of implementing a telegram/discord message). If that is the case, I don't even need a full url list as file, just a file with the url(s) that gave a status 200.

Any ideas how to do this?

```
import requests
import csv
import time

import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()

SLEEP = 0.3 
url_list = []
url_statuscodes = []
url_statuscodes.append(["url","status_code"]) 


def getStatuscode(url):
    try:
        r = requests.head(url,verify=False,timeout=5) # it is faster to only request the header
        return (r.status_code)

    except:
        return -1


with open('urls.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        url_list.append(row[0])


for url in url_list:
    print(url)
    check = [url,getStatuscode(url)]
    time.sleep(SLEEP)
    url_statuscodes.append(check)


with open("urls_withStatusCode.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(url_statuscodes)
```

I tried checking for 200 but it didn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

The `Response.status_code` attribute is an `int`, so a normal equality check should work:

```py
if r.status_code == 200:
    pass
```

If you wish to accept any status code below 400, however, `Response.ok` can be used instead.